# Test A Spring Validator Message

Tags: spring, validation, resources, junit

I have a Spring validator that contains the following code.

```
errors.rejectValue("myFieldName", "errors.required", new Object[] { "My Field" }, "Field required");
```

I want to test that the `errors.required` message is being picked up. I haven't been able to find out how. What I have so far in jUnit is:

```
FieldError fieldError = errors.getFieldErrors().get(0);
assertEquals("myFieldName", fieldError.getField());
assertEquals("errors.required", fieldError.getCode());
//TODO: test that the message was picked up
```

Does anyone know how to grab the full message, with it's arguments, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution.

Inside my jUnit test, I wire in the `MessageSource`.

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

Then I wrote a convenience method.

```
private String getConfiguredMessage(FieldError fieldError) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(fieldError.getCode(), 
                                    fieldError.getArguments(), 
                                    Locale.US);
}
```

Using this method, I can find out what the configured message will be.

```
assertEquals("My Field is required.", getConfiguredMessage(fieldError));
```

Although this solution doesn't truly "get" the message from the error, it serves it's purpose.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: And this test will fail on systems where default locale isn't english